# How do I resolve a "Exception: Service Error: Drive" for folder.addViewer();?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am new to using Google Script and am trying to fix a pre-existing script. My organization uses a Google apps script to add and remove bulk viewers and editors to a folder. Every time I try and run the script, I get an error message saying

> "Exception: Service Error: Drive"

@ the line in the code which contains:

```
folder.addViewer();
```

what can I do to resolve this error?

For context, this is the section of code that line belongs to. `userstoadd` and `editorstoadd` are both variables.

```js
function autoadd() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderid");
  var usersheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('name');
  var viewers = folder.getViewers();
  var editors = folder.getEditors();
  viewers = viewers.map(function(item) {
    return
    item.getEmail().toLowerCase();
  }).sort();
  editors = editors.map(function(item) {
    return item.getEmail().toLowerCase();
  }).sort();
  viewers = viewers.concat(editors);
  var userstoadd = usersheet.getRange('H2:H').getValues().filter(String).map(function(item) {
    return item[0].toLowerCase();
  });
  var editorstoadd = usersheet.getRange('C2:C').getValues().filter(String).map(function(item) {
    return item[0].toLowerCase();
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < userstoadd.length; i++) {
    if (viewers.indexOf(userstoadd[i]) == -1 && editorstoadd.indexOf(userstoadd[i]) == -1) {
      folder.addViewer(userstoadd[i]);
      console.log(userstoadd[i]);
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < editorstoadd.length; i++) {
    if (editors.indexOf(editorstoadd[i]) == -1) {
      folder.addEditor(editorstoadd[i]);
      console.log(editorstoadd[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] and a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I am really new to Google Script and I'm not sure how to recreate the code to single out the error. I updated my question with more of the code... does that help any?

Comment: Thanks for replying. 1. Please add some sample data that is being returned by `usersheet.getRange('C2:C').getValues()`, 2. Move `console.log(userstoadd[i]);` before `folder.addViewer(userstoadd[i]);` , then execute again and the resulting execution logs to the question.

Comment: I see you mention 'userstoadd' and 'editorstoadd' are both variables. What about 'folderid' and 'name'? Are they pre-defined variables as well?